# cyclic functions

Tags: calculus

Can anyone help me with this exercise:
Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable function:
Prove the following:

1. If $f$ is cyclic with cycle $T$, then also $f'$ is cyclic with cycle $T$.
2. If $f$ is even, then, $f'(0)=0$

Thanks!

Comment: What is a cyclic function?

Comment: Does cyclic function mean also periodic function?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you mean *cyclic=periodic*, thus, for some $T$, $\forall x \in \Bbb R, \; f(x+T)=f(x)$

Just take the definition of the derivative:

$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

Then

$$f'(x+T)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+T+h)-f(x+T)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=f'(x)$$

Thus $f'$ is periodic with the same period than $f$.

And if $f$ is even (periodic or not),

$$f'(0)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}+\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(-h)-f(0)}{-h}\right)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h)-f(-h)}{2h}$$

But since $f$ is even, $f(h)=f(-h)$ so the limit is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Same as @arbautjc, except I don't understand why you need to go from the definition. Just use the chain rule to differentiate $f(x+T).$